# How do I setup the image quality using Doxygen and Graphviz

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz

How do I increase the DPI value of the pictures using Graphviz (dot)?

Edit:

I want to create rtf files with a higher resolution of the pictures.
svg files doesnt work since Word  shows errors when open it.
I've tried the different .png formats (gd and cairo) according to the homepage.
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:png
In the graphviz/bin Folder is a config.h file which has on line 21 the setting:

```
/* Default DPI. */

#define DEFAULT_DPI 96
```

Changing these value doesn't have an effect when generating the pictures with doxygen.
So my question is, is there a setting to increase the dpi / pixels for the generated pictures.

Versions:

- Doxygen Version is 1.8.19
- dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
- Microsoft Word: 2002(Build 12527.20988)

Comment: Question is quite unclear! What are you doing? We have to guess that you used doxygen and generate some graphs with dot. Which version of doxygen? Maybe you should have a look at the doxygen configuration setting `DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT` and set it to `svg`

Comment: You wrote: "In the graphviz/bin Folder is a config.h file which has on line 21 the setting: `#define DEFAULT_DPI 96`", after changing this value did you recompile graphviz?

Comment: I did a quick test for rtf when using in the doxygen ssource code `-Gdpi=300`. The result is that the image only appears to be larger in the output (also in html). So it doesn't look like a easy solution possible. Maybe an enhancement request at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose

Comment: I tried svg images in OpenOffice (4.1.7) and here it works, in word (2007) it doesn't but maybe there is a plugin for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your affort and the informations and sorry for my late reply.
I've created an enhancement request as suggested by albert. [link](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8024)